# Ruby Mechanize retrieve headers

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm using mechanize for web inspection, when I get a URL I get a refresh
URL in the headers:

```
meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=/html/Splash.action?splash="
```

When I ask to mechanize to list the metadata I do this:

pp $page.meta

I get:

```
Mechanize::Page::Meta
  ""
  "http://localhost/html/Splash.action?splash="
```

How can I cleanly retrieve the refresh URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$page.meta.first.href
```

Answer (score 0):

Either it's a bug in mechanize, or there's something wrong with the html, as it should have this is meta.
BTW, Mechanize also has #follow_meta_refresh attribute, which is false by default.